# Reading values from zsh's named directory table from Python

Tags: python, zsh

Given a zsh instance that have an entry `my_private_dir` in it's named directory table and the zsh instance is used to launch a Python script. How could Python read the value of `my_private_dir`?

For example

```sh
$ hash -d my_private_dir=/media/user/encrypted_dir
$ hash -d | grep my_private_dir | sed 's/.*=//'
/media/user/encrypted_dir
$ python
>>> get_zsh_named_dir('my_private_dir') # How could python read it?
```

I've tried `system.os`. But it doesn't work, which is expected as it launches a new instance of the shell. Which is a new process and may not have the same named directory table.

```
# Continuing from the previous code snippet
>>> import os
>>> os.system("echo $SHELL")
/bin/zsh
0
>>> os.system("hash -d | grep my_private_dir | sed 's/.*=//'")
0
```

So, how could Python read data from the parent zsh's hash table?

Comment: In general, a process running in a shell can't access any information from the shell running it unless it is specifically exposed, whether as an argument, environment variable, or file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadly speaking, nothing from your shell is exposed to processes running in it unless exposed specifically, such as via an environment variable. So all you need to do is find a way to expose that table to Python.

You can do this by reading the data into Python as a script, and running Python with `-i` to make it become interactive afterwards.

To feed input to a script while still allowing Python to become interactive, the input can't be given as stdin. But luckily, zsh (and bash) have a way to redirect command output as if it were a file, and Python has an easy way to read input from files.

Here's the script: it reads equals-separated key/value pairs [from files and/or standard input](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/fileinput.html) into a dictionary named `eqdict`.

```
"""eqdict.py

Translate equals-separated key/value lines into a Python dict.
"""
try:
    import fileinput
    eqdict = {}
    for line in fileinput.input():
        key, val = line.rstrip().split('=', 1)
        eqdict[key] = val
finally:
    # Don't pollute the global namespace
    del fileinput, line, key, val
```

And this is how you can use it:

```
zsh% hash -d some_name=./some_dir/
zsh% python3 -i eqdict.py <(hash -d)
>>> eqdict['some_name']
'./some_dir/'
```

Comment: This is brilliant! May you pont me to a description of how redirecting to a file that doesn't exist in the fs works?

Comment: [Here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_7.html) is the relevant page of Zsh's documentation (and [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution) for Bash). This is also detailed in `man zshexpn` (or `man bash`), under "Process Substitution". Also, if my answer solved your problem, please accept it.